# NIFI(SECURE):SSLPeerUndefinedException:Hsotname

Tags: ssl, apache-nifi

I want  to use  rest api inside  secure nifi. I have  added  sslcontextService  with it's  trustore JKS file but when I use invokehttp processor with this url  to get  kerberos  token:`https://ip here/nifi-api/access/kerberos` I got  this error :**SSLPeerUndefinedException:Hostname**

1. in my jks   file subjectAltname is empty this  can  be a reason  for
   failure?
2. also  I want to know after  getting  token  I can use it   for autorization and  then use  rest api as I  want or  is there any 
   other  subjects  I should  pay attention to?

Answer (score 2):

There is no exception class in Apache NiFi or the underlying libraries called `SSLPeerUndefinedException`. I suspect what you are encountering is `SSLPeerUnverifiedException`. This exception is thrown when the remote endpoint does not provide a certificate or the certificate chain cannot be verified.

There are a couple steps you can take to try and identify the issue:

1. Ensure that the certificate that your NiFi instance is presenting is in the truststore as well. The `PrivateKeyEntry` should be loaded in the keystore (`keystore.jks` or similar), but the truststore is different -- it contains the `trustedCertEntry` which contains the `SubjectKeyIdentifier` and the various certificate fingerprints (MD5, SHA1, SHA-256) so that it can assert the validity of services that present those certificates. If the `SSLContextService` associated with the `InvokeHTTP` processor cannot verify the certificate presented by NiFi, it won't allow the connection.
2. Try to use `curl` or another command-line tool like [Nipyapi](https://nipyapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html) to connect to the NiFi API and verify the connection.

A Kerberos ticket is used for *authentication* -- proving you/the client are who you claim to be via knowledge/possession of some secret value. *Authorization*, or determining the allowed actions and privileges, is a separate process.

The `subjectAltName` being empty in a certificate can cause issues for new browsers, as based on [RFC 6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125) which says that the SAN must be checked first, but I don't believe the current version of the `okhttp` library in use here enforces that. You should populate the SAN field for future compatibility though.